# При загрузки нескольких изображений, в бд приходит 1

Tags: yii2, phpmyadmin, php7

### Model

```
[['imageFiles'], 'file',
            'skipOnEmpty' => false,
            'extensions' => 'png, jpg',
            'maxFiles' => 4
            ],

public function upload()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        foreach ($this->imageFiles as $file) {
            $filename=Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generateRandomString(15);
            // echo $filename;
            $file->saveAs('web/uploads/' . 'phone_' .  $filename . '.' . $file->extension);
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Product();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'imageFiles');
        if ($model->validate() && $uploadedFileName = $model->upload())
        {
            $model->image = $uploadedFileName;

            $model->save(false);

            // установка флеш-сообщения, для улучшения юзабилити
            Yii::$app->session
                ->setFlash('success', 'Товар успешно добавлен!');
            // перенаправление на главную
            return $this->redirect(['/catalog']);
        }
    }
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

### Form

```
<div class="catalog-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<?= $form->field($model,'imageFiles[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*']) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: $uploadedFileName по идее сюда пишет только последний файл. Из за этого и только 1 запись. А файлы все загружены?

Comment: да всё сохраняется в папку

Comment: `if ($model->validate() && $uploadedFileName = $model->upload())
        {
            $model->image = $uploadedFileName;

            $model->save(false);
        }` Насколько я понимаю здесь ты сохраняешь в базу только последнюю картинку

Comment: Усть варианты решения? А то у меня уже кончились варианты

Comment: У тебя связь 1 продукт много картинок? Картинки отдельной моделью сохраняются?

Comment: Нет, картинки и остальные поля сохраняются одной моделью

Comment: Картинки хранятся в той же таблице что и продукт?

Comment: Сделай скрин бд как хранятся картинки

Comment: скриншот прикреплён ниже формы, поле image

Comment: А где название или путь к картинке?

Comment: В том то и дело приходит просто еденица, а не путь к картинке, а если одну загружаю без цикла то приходит

Comment: Ты в методе возвращаешь bool. Возвращайся масс6

Comment: Ты в методе возвращаешь bool . Возвращай массив названий и сохраняй, в чем проблема?

Comment: А лучше обернись все в транзакцию